# How can I simulate events like Series1DblClick or Chart1ClickSeries when programatically creating Charts and Series on the runtime?

Tags: delphi, teechart

In a small Delphi program I create few TCharts and TBarSeries programmatically on the runtime but then I want to be able to click on a bar of the chart and fire, for example, a Chart1ClickSeries event to display information of that bar. Is that possible??

Comment: Simply assign a method to the `OnClickSeries` event.

Comment: What version of Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your event handler:

```
TForm1 = class...
  ...
  procedure BarSeries1Click(Sender: TChartSeries;
    ValueIndex: Integer; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
    Y: Integer);
  procedure BarSeries1DblClick(Sender: TChartSeries;
    ValueIndex: Integer; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
    Y: Integer);
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.BarSeries1Click(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('Click');
end;

procedure TForm1.BarSeries1DblClick(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('DblClick');
end;
```

Then after you've created your Series, assign the events:

```
BarSeries1.OnClick:=BarSeries1Click;
BarSeries1.OnDblClick:=BarSeries1DblClick;
```